# CSS specificity of the flex property over flex-basis

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-specificity

Can someone tell me if there is a spicificity among CSS properies?

I am testing flexbox and I tried this scenario:

The second selector `.flex-basis-5` is applied via JS on some kind of condition.
I was expecting the value of flex-basis to be overwritten by new selector, but it's only applied if I add `!important` to it.

```
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}

.flex-item-7 {
  flex: 0 0 58.33%
}

.flex-basis-5 {
  flex-basis: 41.66%;
}
```

```
<div class="flex-container">    
   <div class="flex-item-7 flex-basis-5">Some content</div>
</div>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Specificity is based on the selector, not the property. Properties applied to a selector are applied in the order written, so lower down properties within the set will override higher up values.

This said, your code works if I understand you correctly. Here's a demo:

```js
const btn = document.getElementById("toggle")
btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  document.querySelector(".flex-item-7").classList.toggle("flex-basis-5")
})
```

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}

.flex-item-7 {
  flex: 0 0 58.33%;
  background: #ccc;
}

.flex-basis-5 {
  flex-basis: 41.66%;
}

button {
  margin-top: 2em;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">    
   <div class="flex-item-7 flex-basis-5">Some content</div>
</div>

<button id="toggle">Toggle .flex-basis-5</button>
```

If you're seeing something different in your app, it's likely that you have `.flex-basis-5` defined above `.flex-item-7`, so it has lower precedence and is being overridden by the later-defined styles.

Comment: That was fast!!
Thank you coreyward for your speedy answer it makes sense.
I was only looking at the order the selectors where applied to the element.

Comment: Precedence is the right word in this case!